# ERROR: collation "database_default" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, collation

Moving application from SQL Server to PostgreSQL Database. I am getting this error from one of the queries used in a Java file:

> ERROR: collation "database_default" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
> Position: 467. Stacktrace follows:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: collation "database_default" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
> Position: 467

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`database_default` is a SQL Server-specific collation that explicitly tells SQL Server to use the database's default collation, overriding the default collation precedence behavior. This is used in a `COLLATE` clause most typically to avoid collation conflict errors that arise when using temp tables in scenarios where `tempdb`'s default collation differs from the current database's default collation and string columns are being joined or concatenated.

The Java code would need to be edited to remove the `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` from the query. Though if this app is coded for Microsoft SQL Server, will it work in PostgreSQL even if this one part is fixed? There are other SQL syntax and datatype differences between the RDBMSs.

For more information on migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL, please see:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server

However, if you are dealing with a 3rd party app that has embedded T-SQL, then you might be forced to contact the software vendor to ask about the potential for PostgreSQL support.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you could use `COLLATE "default"` to get the default collation (the double quotes are required), but it is better to omit that.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe your solution is working.

Comment: @AshishKumarRoy You never indicated whether or not this was in-house or 3rd party code. Please update the question with that info. And, have you tried simply removing the `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` clause?